# Validation of non empty on next button for multiple uitextfields in uitableview Cell

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, validation, uitextfield

In my view controller I have a table view in which I am loading multiple tableview cells. Some have UITextfield,Labels,Radio and check buttons. Now I have done all the part showing and entering data in tableview cell but not able to check whether any one field is left empty.
On button click in my controller I need to check this validation if all fields are non-empty. Or How can I get data from each field on button click.
Here is my cellForRowAt indexpath code that will give idea of diff cell I am loading. How can I validate if my uitextfield are empty and radio button are checked.

```
          func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

       switch indexPath.row {

       case 0:
           let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "StartEndDateCell", for: indexPath) as! StartEndDateCell
           //cell with 2 textfield
           return cell

       case 1:
           let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "NameTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! NameTableViewCell
           //cell with single textField
           return cell

       case 2:
           let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "StartEnddateTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! StartEnddateTableViewCell
           //cell open UIDATEPICKER here on click of textfield contains 2 textfield
           return cell

       case 3:
           let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "AmountTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! AmountTableViewCell
           //cell with single textfield with numeric keyboard
           return cell

       case 4:
           let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MaxFixTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! MaxFixTableViewCell

           return cell
         //cell with radio buttons

       case 5:
           let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "infoTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! infoTableViewCell
           //for oneTimeLabel
           let tapGestureFrequency : UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer.init(target: self, action: #selector(freqLblClick(tapGestureFrequency:)))
           tapGestureFrequency.delegate = self as? UIGestureRecognizerDelegate
           tapGestureFrequency.numberOfTapsRequired = 1

           cell.oneTimeLabel.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
           cell.oneTimeLabel.tag = 1
           cell.oneTimeLabel.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureFrequency)


           //for onLabel
           let tapGestureOnDebit : UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer.init(target: self, action: #selector(lblClickDebit(tapGestureOnDebit:)))
           tapGestureOnDebit.delegate = self as? UIGestureRecognizerDelegate
           tapGestureOnDebit.numberOfTapsRequired = 1

           cell.onLabel.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
           cell.onLabel.tag = 2
           cell.onLabel.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureOnDebit)
           return cell

       case 6:
           let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "RemarksTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! RemarksTableViewCell

           return cell

       case 7:
           let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "InformTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! InformTableViewCell
           return cell


       default:
           let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "checkTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! checkTableViewCell
           return cell
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can implement `UITextFieldDelegate` to track and update your data, for `UITableViewCell`s with `UITextField`. But this requires you to write implement text delegate in each of the cell where you need to update your data set. Additionally for switch controls and check boxes you can monitor their `valueChanged` event.

For example

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if let text = textField.text, let textRange = Range(range, in: text) {
        let updatedText = text.replacingCharacters(in: textRange, with: string)

        UserData.shared.name = updatedText
    }

    return true
}

 @IBAction func switchValueChanged(_ sender: Any) {
     UserData.shared.setting = switchControl.isOn
 }
```

Comment: Actually,its my mistake I did not mention where I need to implement validation in my question, I need to check validation on button click on which it is navigating to other view controller.
if any text field is left emptied on button remains uncheck I need to show error or pop-up.
Basically I need to avoid user to navigate to other view controller untill an unless all the fileds are filled. How can I get data entered in filelds on button click.

Comment: Does your button be a part of UITableViewCell? Probably not, in this case you only need to update your data as mentioned in the answer and need to validate that data  before actual navigation.

Comment: bhai: Thanks for updating the answer it really helped me for an approach. Kindly update it with empty validation as I did in my answer. If it works I will mark your answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to store this data somewhere, specially because UITableView reuse its cells, so you might lose what was inputed if the user scrolls.

Assuming you have an array where the the info for each cell comes from, you can create a flag that explicits if the user has answered that question. On `cellForRowAtindexPath` you'll check if the field is empty and reload the answer/state.

After that, you can create a validationMethod that should be called after every cell input, based on your local array of fields + answers.

Comment: I have a different TableViewCell classes for each cell where I have done the work of selecting and entering data and showing them as each cell has diiferent functionality.
On cellForRowAtIndexPath I can check if fields are empty or not but the validation is need to be set on button click where navigation is done. I need to now how can I access tableview/tableview cell to check if it is empty on button click.

Answer (score 0):

all other validation like numeric type and date type i have done in cell class. I know it is not the proper way to do it. We can save our values to model class and use model class instead of doing it. doing in this way may reult in failure of validation when we scroll our tableview, but for now it is working in my code. Still I am waiting to do it in a write way. I will not mark my question as answered

at button click

```
@IBAction func nextButtonClicked(_ sender: Any) {
        let nameCell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: 1, section: 0)) as? NameTableViewCell
        if (nameCell?.nameTextField.text!.isEmpty)! {
           Log.i("TextField is Empty---" )
        }
        let startEndDateCell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row : 2,section : 0)) as? StartEnddateTableViewCell
        if((startEndDateCell?.startDateTextField.text!.isEmpty)! || (startEndDateCell?.endDateTextField.text!.isEmpty)!){
            Log.i("Start And End Date Empty")
        }
        let amountCell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row : 3, section : 0))as? AmountTableViewCell
        if (amountCell?.amountTextField.text!.isEmpty)! {
            Log.i("Amount Cell Empty---")
        }

        else{
        let vc = NextViewController(nibName: "NextViewController", bundle: nil)
        navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true )
        }
    }
```